# Rust (criterion): how to pass mutable reference within bench_with_input()

Tags: sorting, rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo, rust-criterion

I am new to Rust and am trying to benchmark sorting algorithms.

The functions take immutable references to a slice (`fn sort(&self, slice: &mut [T])`).

I am trying to use the `criterion` crate to benchmark them for different inputs (random vectors of increasing length).

However I cannot figure out how to pass the vectors to the functions as mutable references. I have tried the the fixes suggested by `rustc` but each generates another error.

The benchmark code is (shortened example to exclude all the functions):

```rust
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, BenchmarkId, Criterion, Throughput};
use rand::{distributions::Uniform, Rng};
use sorting::*;

fn sorting_benchmarks(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("Sorting");

    for i in [1, 10, 100].iter() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let range = Uniform::new(0, 100);
        let nums: Vec<usize> = (0..(*i)).map(|_| rng.sample(&range)).collect();

        let mut v = black_box(nums.to_vec());
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Bubble Sort {}", i), &v, |b, v| {
            b.iter(|| BubbleSort.sort(v))
        });
    group.finish();
}
```

The function for `BubbleSort.sort` is:

```rust
impl<T> Sorter<T> for BubbleSort {
    fn sort(&self, arr: &mut [T])
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        let mut swapped = true;
        while swapped {
            swapped = false;
            for i in 1..arr.len() {
                if arr[i - 1] > arr[i] {
                    arr.swap(i - 1, i);
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some examples of the error messages.

First:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> benches/criterion_bench.rs:16:39
   |
15 |         group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Bubble Sort {}", i), &v, |b, v| {
   |                                                                               - help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut v`
16 |             b.iter(|| BubbleSort.sort(&mut v))
   |                                       ^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

If I do the suggested fix, I still get `cannot borrow as mutable`.

I have successfully benchmarked the functions using `bench_function` from the `criterion` crate. But this does not help me with benchmarking against **multiple** inputs for comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct problem in your code is that you used `&v` where you needed `&mut v`. But that's not actually going to work well, and you should not be using `bench_with_input` for this purpose. (In fact, I'm not sure what `bench_with_input` is good for — closure captures work just fine.)

The key thing to understand is that Criterion is going to run your benchmarked function *many times* (when you call `iter`). If you did arrange to pass a mutable reference to the same vector for each run, that would not be appropriate for benchmarking a sorting algorithm because it means all iterations but the first would receive already-sorted input. When the performance of the algorithm depends on the order of the input, you want a fresh non-sorted vector each time.

When you want to benchmark a function that consumes or mutates input, you use a different [`Bencher`](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/struct.Bencher.html) method than `iter()`. In particular, [`iter_batched_ref()`](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/struct.Bencher.html#method.iter_batched_ref) is most appropriate for benchmarking a sorting algorithm (or any other function which takes a mutable reference and mutates it).

```rust
fn sorting_benchmarks(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("Sorting");

    for i in [1, 10, 100] {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let range = Uniform::new(0, 100);

        group.bench_function(BenchmarkId::new("Bubble Sort {}", i), |b| {
            b.iter_batched_ref(
                || -> Vec<usize> { (0..i).map(|_| rng.sample(&range)).collect() },
                |v| BubbleSort.sort(v),
                BatchSize::SmallInput,
            )
        });
    }
    group.finish();
}
```

Notice that the input vector is constructed inside of a function passed to `iter_batched_ref`. `iter_batched_ref` will call that function several times, then call the function being benchmarked several times to measure it, with a fresh input each time.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice, it seems to work nicely now. I also want to ensure that each sorting function gets the same vector. Instead of `let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();` once at the start of the loop, would I need to do something like `let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(1234);` before each sorting function ?

Comment: @FISR You would need to create the RNG inside the closure that creates the `Vec`, so that each one has a fresh RNG with identical state. However, a better idea then would be to create the Vec once and `clone` it for each sort operation — this will be cheaper. That is, the initialization closure becomes `|| initial_vec.clone()`.